# Commit from directory, not under version control, to override current revision

Tags: svn, version-control

The title is propably misleading so I try to explain my situation.

I have a Subversion repository and a revision that is older than the head revision, I call it now revision X. My revision was changed (X+1) and ripped off the version control system. There are no `.svn` directories or something like this in this local folder.

I would like to commit this X+1 revision to my repository as head. My problem is how to do this.
It's kind of a branch but it's not done correctly so I have to face this problem now.

All changes made between X and head should not be in the new head, but all changes between X and X+1 must be in head.

I hope my explanation is understandable.

**Edit:**
I don't know, which revision X is. I just have the non-versioned working copy without any information. That's the biggest problem. Sorry for not mentioning this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fastest way would probably be to checkout the repository to a different folder, revert it to version X, then copy your "X+1" files to the working copy you checked out, overwriting any existing conflicts, and then commit.

Comment: Your idea is good, I propably can use it. The problem is that there are files in X that are not in X+1.

Comment: that's not a problem, only the changed files will be committed, if you have files in X+1 that are not in X, that's a different matter - you'll have to add them before the commit.

Comment: But I don't want to have these files in head. The other aspect is in the edit of my question: I don't know which revsion X is.

Comment: Hmm. If you remove all of the files from a checked out working copy of the head (but leave the .svn directories), and then paste in the contents of your X+1 directory, you could then probably do an svn diff to determine what has changed between your X+1 copy and the current head.

Comment: That's a neat way... I'll try it.

Comment: You could also use rsync to make your working copy look like X+1. In Git I’d just put X+1 on its own branch and then merge it in; while you could try that in SVN, I’m not sure its merge support is up to the task.